# What is the max image size when using createImage in Google Slides API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-slides-api

When using Google Slides API to create a slide and then create an image within that slide I am getting an error

```
Invalid requests[19].createImage: The provided image is too large.
```

The size of the image in the provided url is `4.9MB`. On [wikipedia page about Google Slides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Slides#Supported_file_formats_and_limits) it states that `Images inserted cannot be larger than 50 MB`, yet my image is 10 times smaller.

I have tried creating the presentation manually on the Google Slides, and importing the image via url, and that way it works.

I can't find the maximum size limit anywhere in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [Google Slides API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request),

`createImage` is a `CreateImageRequest` object.
Under `CreateImageRequest`, it specifically states the following:

- Images must be less than 50MB in size
- Cannot exceed 25 megapixels
- Must be in one of PNG, JPEG, or GIF format.
- The provided URL can be at most 2 kB in length (url length should be maximum of 2000 characters).

[image: sample image]

Comment: Of course, I forgot to check the number of pixels my image has. It has 48 megapixels which is way over the limit of 25 megapixels. I was so occupied around the image size of ~5MB that I did not check the number of pixels. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. It is always a combination of resolution and size when it comes to limitations. Glad I was of help. Good luck.